# TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable and SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please I need help my `csv` file downloaded from  this site

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/state-drug-utilization-data-2016
and I am working by pandas to analyses it I need to reach to column in the file and I do this

```
import pandas as pd
url = "E:\dataset\state_dataset\Drug_Utilization_2017_-_California.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.shape
df.columns()
```

and the error was

> TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable

when I try to  Know the type of one column in the file I do this

```
    type(df.'state'[0])
```

and "state" is an column in my csv file and the error was

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Sorry to send two types of error but I am really try so many times and I fail.

Comment: type(df['state'][0])

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It may be helpful to follow a tutorial on how to use pandas:

```
df.columns
```

is not callable, you cannot `df.columns()` it, hence `TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable`.

```
type(df.'state'[0])
```

is not how you get a column in pandas, they are not attributes of the dataframe and you can't use strings as attribute names, hence the SyntaxError:

```
df['state'][0]
```

is how you would get the first item in the 'state' column.

Comment: thank you sir for your cooperation df.columns is work but df['state'][0] dose not work, Iam follow many tutorial on how to use pandas, I want to reach the values in some column to process them like filter the columns values under some condition

Comment: `print(df.columns)` will show you what columns are available and `df['columnname']` is how you access a column.

Comment: Thank you sir for your generosity and communication with me. I am trying to divide my data set by drugs name, which is a field in the data set. For example, there is a set of records for the drug of 'Dexamethas' I want to be in a data frame and doing some processing on it and the drug 'SPRINTEC 2' in another data frame and so on. Please keep in help  me because I need to follow the notes. Thank you sir,